# Concrete post base wood too tight

Tags: concrete, post, anchor, pressure-treated

I'm using the Simpson PB66Z "Galvanized Post Base" to attach my pressure treated 6x6 to the footing. The wood seems to be slightly too large to fit such that the bottom of the post rests on the metal.

What's the proper way to handle this? I could pound it with a sledge hammer, shave some wood off on the two side corners, or something else? What is commonly done?

**Edit:** Added picture of the issue.
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Could you give us a picture of the post base not fitting onto the post?

Comment: I have edited the post with a picture, @DanielGriscom. I'd guess the wood will shrink a bit as it dries more, but it doesn't seem particularly wet when I cut it.

Comment: Not sure what is commonly done, but pounding a scape on top with a sledge hammer seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Would you mind posting an answer to that effect? Bonus points if it has an "after" picture. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up, I did use a sledge hammer to pound them into place. I placed a small cut piece of the 6x6 on top to prevent the post from getting messed up. It wedged it in there quite well.

[image]